# Unwanted space added by Mathjax in doxygen

Tags: latex, doxygen, mathjax

When adding any latex equation into doxygen via mathjax right after ( there is an additional unwanted space added.

For example `(\f$m\f$)` produces ( m) in the generated html code.

Image of space appearing after '(' in doxygen generated html files

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to fix it besides having mathjax generate the ()?

Code:

```
/**   @brief Calculates Earth Similarity Index (\f$ESI\f$) of a planet.
*
*   The earth similarity index is a number that denotes how similar a planet is to that of earth. 1 is being exactly earth like.
*
*   @param  planetMeanRadius \f$r\f$(\f$m\f$) is the mean radius of a planet.
*   @param  planetBulkDensity \f$\rho\f$(\f$\frac{kg}{m^3}\f$) is the bulk density of the planet.
*   @param  planetEscapeVelocity \f$v_e\f$(\f$\frac{m}{s}\f$) is the escape velocity. The velocity needed to escape the planet's gravitational pull.
*   @param  planetSurfaceTemperature \f$T\f$(\f$K\f$) is the average surface temperature of the planet.
*   @return \f$ESI\f$(dimensionless) Earth Similarity Index for a planet.
*   @see PlanetSimilarityIndex() for \f$ESI\f$ equation using any planet as reference.
*   @see EarthSimilarityIndexInterior() for \f$ESI_I\f$ equation.
*   @see EarthSimilarityIndexSurface() for \f$ESI_S\f$ equation.
*/ 
template<typename T>
T EarthSimilarityIndex( const T& planetMeanRadius, const T& planetBulkDensity, const T& planetEscapeVelocity, const T& planetSurfaceTemperature );
```

Ran on Doxygen 1.8.13

Comment: Is the space inside the mathjax block or before it?

Comment: When using an image include the image and not a link. Which version of doxygen are we talking about? @PeterKrautzberger the space is inserted by doxygen (I just tested it and it is from doxygen, probably because of word endings).

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the information as shown in the picture (strangely it now shows, but remark about link is still valid), i.e just the documentation and prototype of the function will probably be enough.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger There is no space inside or before. I posted the code that generated it.

Comment: @albert Code has been added. It was ran on 1.8.13

Comment: @Metex I meant the space in the output. If it's outside of the MathJax output, then it likely won't be a problem with MathJax.

Comment: Why don't you put the ( and ) as part of the formula?

Comment: @albert I want to avoid putting it as part of the formula for two reasons. One being it looks visually odd when you compare it to the rest of the documentation. Two, When writing my phd I encountered a situation once or twice where adding ( and ) to an inline formula looked off center. The advice given was to put the ( and ) outside the formula.

Comment: I understand, you especially mean the case of r(m) where the "(" stick out.